# Trying to understand what the rerenderpin function is doing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pinterest

I'm a newbie to JavaScript and am helping out a friend maintain his website. The only thing I cannot figure out what his index.html page is doing revolves around this piece of JavaScript code. I have a few questions about it below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reRenderPin() {
    for (var n in window) {
        if ( n.indexOf('PIN_') == 0 && $("a[data-pin-do]").length > 0)  {
            $("a[data-pin-do]").attr("id", "pinbutton");
            var element = document.getElementById('pinbutton');
            window[n].f.render.buttonBookmark( element );
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    reRenderPin();
});

$(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", function(e, pid) {
    reRenderPin();
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

I did searches on this but none of the responses were clear to me.

I know this has something to do with Pinterest and I understand that the reRenderPin() function is being called at "document ready" time and "projectLoadComplete" time.

My questions are:

1. What is the reRenderPin() function doing?
2. When does the projectLoadComplete event occur? I did a search on this and there was very little information on it and what was there was not clear to me.
3. I noticed that the function uses a "$" function. I know this is a JQuery funcntion but my understaning with JQuery funcntions is that if you use them you have to have a link to the code library in your html. The only .js library on the page is the one pointing to the pinterest assests - see code. How is this "$" function working with no library?

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Regards,
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

The script seems to be a pinterest pin button script.

Possibly inserted by the CMS or template you are using

1) the script likely inserts jQuery when needed

2) the code looks for a variable in the window scope that starts with PIN_ and looks for a link with data-pin-do and a matching function window["pin_something"].f.

3) projectLoadComplete is triggered by another script and when triggered the reRender is called - it seems this is related to a platform called cargo - http://support.cargocollective.com/customer/portal/articles/708669-adding-a-pinterest-widget

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I'm still not getting it. What do you mean "the script likely inserts jQuery when needed"?  I guess I wasn't clear but instead of a technical answer I am looking more for a functional answer - Why is this function on the page? What is it doing to the page? sorry if I wasn't clear.